# simple countdown to halloween project

Tags: javascript, beginner

I just started to learning JavaScript and i did this below code for a simple countdown to halloween project

```
// Setting counter start date
const year = new Date().getFullYear()

let timeInterval
let countdownWasStarted = false
let deadline = new Date("Oct 31, " + year)

// Function that starts the counter
function initCountdown() {

    // Stores the total time in milliseconds until halloween
    const untilH = (deadline - new Date())

    // Check if the year is a leap year and if the start date has expired
    const isLeapYear = !((year % 4) && (year % 100) || !(year % 400))
     
    if (year != isLeapYear && untilH <= 0) {
        deadline = new Date(deadline.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        countdownWasStarted = true
        updateTime()
    }

    else if (year == isLeapYear && untilH.total <= 0) {
        deadline = new Date(deadline.getTime() + 366 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        countdownWasStarted = true
        updateTime()
    }
    // Run the updateTime function every 1 second
    timeInterval = setInterval(updateTime, 1000)
}

// Converts days, hours, minutes and seconds to singular when they should be singular
function singular(value, singular, plural) {

    if(value == 1) {
        return singular
    } else {
        plural = singular + "s"
        return plural
    }
}

// Reset the counter
function resetCountdown() {
    
    clearInterval(timeInterval)
    initCountdown()
}

// Function that manipulates the DOM and calculates the days, hours, minutes and seconds until halloween
function updateTime() {

        // Stores the total time in milliseconds until halloween
        const untilHalloween = (deadline - new Date())

        // Stores the current year of the deadline variable
        const deadlineYear = deadline.getFullYear()

        // If the counter has expired, call the resetCountdown function to reset it
        if(countdownWasStarted == false && deadlineYear == year && untilHalloween <= 0) {
            resetCountdown()
        }
        // If the counter has already restarted, reset the variable countdownWasStarted to false
        else if(deadlineYear != year && countdownWasStarted != false) {
            countdownWasStarted = !countdownWasStarted
        }

        // Calculating days, hours, minutes and seconds
        const days = Math.floor(untilHalloween / (24*60*60*1000))
        const hours = Math.floor(untilHalloween / (60*60*1000)) % 24
        const minutes = Math.floor(untilHalloween / (60*1000)) % 60
        const seconds = Math.floor(untilHalloween / 1000) % 60
    
        let displayDays = `${singular(days, "day")}`
        let displayHours = `${singular(hours, "hour")}`
        let displayMinu = `${singular(minutes, "minute")}`
        let displaySecs = `${singular(seconds, "second")}`

    
          document.getElementById('singularD').innerHTML = displayDays
          document.getElementById('singularH').innerHTML = displayHours
          document.getElementById('singularM').innerHTML = displayMinu
          document.getElementById('singularS').innerHTML = displaySecs
    
    
          document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days
          document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hours
          document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutes
          document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds
}

// initial call
initCountdown()
```

As I'm learning it would be good to know my mistakes or things I could do better, or even another way to do the counter.

If you guys can help me with this I would be very grateful :)

Answer (score 1):

I've only skimmed this and haven't 100% understood it - specifically the point of the variable `countdownHasStarted` -, but I've spotted a bug. Did you test with both leap and non-leap years?

In `initCountdown` since `year` is a number value and `isLeapYear` is a boolean value the expression `year == isLeapYear` will always return `false`.

---

As a general rule you should be always using `===` instead of `==` unless you have a good reason.

---

You are "hiding" the `initCountdown()` at the end of code. Since `function` ["hoists"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) the declared function, you can call `initCountdown()` directly after your variable declarations.

---

You should consider ending all statements with semicolons. While this isn't a hard rule - many people don't use them - I believe the majority do and using them can avoid some obscure errors.

---

You are not using the `Date` class optimally.

As a minor point, instead of using string parsing at `new Date("Oct 31, " + year)` it would be more straight forward top use the variant `new Date(year, month, day)` and pass in the data as numbers: `new Date(year, 9, 31)` (Notice, October is `9` as counting starts with `0` for January). Or instead of creating a new `Date` object, just modify the existing one:

```
let deadline = new Date();
deadline.setUTCMonth(9, 31);

const year = deadline.getFullYear();
```

More importantly the whole handling leap years yourself is unnecessary. You can use `Date` to add years (or months or days):

```
deadline.setFullYear(deadline.getFullYear() + 1);
```

And there are probably ways to use it to calculate the days/hours/minutes/seconds of the time difference, too.

---

You don't need to use string templates (`` `...` ``) if it only contains the single expression: ̀`` `${singular(days, "day")}` `` can just be `singular(days, "day")`.

---

The function `singluar` shouldn't have `plural` as a parameter but as a local variable (or just `return singular + "s";`)

---

Instead of calling `document.getElementById()` in each loop you should call and store the element references once at the start of the script.

---

Use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` when writing plain text.

Comment: Thank you guys for the time took to help me. Your guys answer was exactly what I was looking for. I'm just a little confused about plain text, what's plain text and why is textContent a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution. Most comments are mentioned in RoToRa's answer.

```js
let HalloweenDate = { month: 9 /*October*/, day: 31 }
function getMillisecondsToHalloween() {
    let now = new Date()
    // I used number arguments, instead of the date string:
    //      This seems more straightforward.
    let nextHalloween = new Date(now.getFullYear(), HalloweenDate.month, HalloweenDate.day)
    if (now > nextHalloween) {
        // I rely on the JavaScript built in Date logic:
        //      It's certainly correct.
        nextHalloween = new Date(now.getFullYear() + 1, HalloweenDate.month, HalloweenDate.day)
    }

    return nextHalloween - now
}

// I renamed the untilH parameter name to durationInMS:
//      I thought this was clearer.
function splitDurationInUnits(durationInMS) {
    const days = Math.floor(durationInMS / (24*60*60*1000))
    const hours = Math.floor(durationInMS / (60*60*1000)) % 24
    const minutes = Math.floor(durationInMS / (60*1000)) % 60
    const seconds = Math.floor(durationInMS / 1000) % 60
    
    return { days, hours, minutes, seconds }
}

// Converts days, hours, minutes and seconds to singular when they should be singular
function singular(value, singular, plural) {
    if(value == 1) {
        return singular
    } else {
        plural = singular + "s"
        return plural
    }
}

// requesting the elements once improves performance
//      because I used requestAnimationFrame, this is important.
//      see RoToRa's answer

// I renamed singularD,... to labelDays,...:
//      It expresses better its purpose.
let labelDays = document.getElementById('labelDays')
let labelHours = document.getElementById('labelHours')
let labelMinutes = document.getElementById('labelMinutes')
let labelSeconds = document.getElementById('labelSeconds')

let outputDays = document.getElementById('days')
let outputHours = document.getElementById('hours')
let outputMinutes = document.getElementById('minutes')
let outputSeconds = document.getElementById('seconds')

function display(durationInUnits) {
    // I used textContent instead of innerHTML (see RoToRa's answer)
    labelDays.textContent = singular(durationInUnits.days, "day")
    labelHours.textContent = singular(durationInUnits.hours, "hour")
    labelMinutes.textContent = singular(durationInUnits.minutes, "minute")
    labelSeconds.textContent = singular(durationInUnits.seconds, "second")

    outputDays.textContent = durationInUnits.days
    outputHours.textContent = durationInUnits.hours
    outputMinutes.textContent = durationInUnits.minutes
    outputSeconds.textContent = durationInUnits.seconds
}

function updateTime() {
    // I separated the calculation logic from the display logic:
    //      I think it improves clarity.
    // It recalculates the next Halloween on every iteration
    //      which will be slower, but I'm more sure I won't have bugs if the timer reaches zero
    //      I could remove the resetCountdown functioon
    let untilHalloween = getMillisecondsToHalloween()
    let durationInUnits = splitDurationInUnits(untilHalloween)
    display(durationInUnits)

    requestAnimationFrame(updateTime)
}

// I use requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval:
//      When I once had to implement a timer, I updated every second
//          I had to improve my work since the tester sometimes saw it skipping seconds.
requestAnimationFrame(updateTime)
```

```html
    <div>
        <div><output id="days"></output> <output id="labelDays"></output></div>
        <div><output id="hours"></output> <output id="labelHours"></output></div>
        <div><output id="minutes"></output> <output id="labelMinutes"></output></div>
        <div><output id="seconds"></output> <output id="labelSeconds"></output></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to do but I didn't understand the date, thanks :)

Comment: I was personally tempted to add 1 thing. On Halloween it will be saying 364 days,... You could instead program it to make it do something special 